# Redis connection slow from PHP

Tags: php, windows, redis, xampp

I just started using Redis in my application, but for some reason the initial connection to the Redis server from PHP takes almost exactly 1 second.  When using Predis, the latency issue doesn't occur until the first `get()` call, and if I try connecting manually the latency occurs on the initial connection via `fsockopen()`.

I've read the [redis latency documentation](http://redis.io/topics/latency), but none of the information seemed relevant to my case.  Running `redis-cli --latency` just seemed to product a garbled mess. I guess my question is what's the best way to troubleshoot this?  Any help would be much appreciated.

**Predis Client instantiation:**

```
$redis = new Predis\Client(array(
    'host'     => 'localhost',
    'port'     => 6379
));
```

**Here's some relevant info:**

- PHP 5.4.7
- XAMPP
- Windows 7 64-bit
- 16GB ram
- The redis server is running locally on port 6379

Comment: Try connecting to redis yourself from netcat or similar to see if the latency comes from the redis server. If not, try to login from php to netcat in listening mode to see if the issue comes from your php socket. At least you will know which side has an issue ...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

On windows always use `127.0.0.1` instead of localhost.

In recent versions of windows resolution of name `localhost` is handled within DNS itself (it is a "feature" to help incorporate IPv6) and this dns query always take 1 sec.